# Is it possible to solve [Errno 32] Broken pipe in using get_coherence()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gensim, topic-modeling, broken-pipe

to make topic modelling, I used this code, but `BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe` error occurs.
how to solve this problem.

```
from gensim.models import CoherenceModel
from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support

coherence_score18=[]
def model_func(corpus18, id2word18, bigram_document18, a):
    for i in range(2,10):
        model18 = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus18, id2word=id2word18, num_topics=i)
        coherence_model18=CoherenceModel(model18, texts=bigram_document18, dictionary=id2word18, coherence=a)
        coherence_lda18=coherence_model18.get_coherence()
        print('n=',i,'Score:',coherence_lda18)
        coherence_score18.append(coherence_lda18)
        

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        freeze_support()
```

Comment: Could you please provide the rest of the code. Because f is not defined in the code which is multi-processing?

Comment: That is my fault. I didn't defined f.